# Android: Does any app use inline editing?

Tags: android, inline-edit

I have a list with items. I want to know, if I can edit the name of the item inline. Just tap and rename the item.
Is this right to make it in android? I don´t see any app that do this...
thanks!

Comment: Generally I think if this items are in a ListView tapping the item would take the user to a new screen that would allow deeper editing. This new screen could just be a dialog that popups up and allows editing the name of the item though. This is also how I'd expect things to work on iOS, but if you have an example of the behavior on a different platform that might help people to come up with suggestions.

Comment: I don´t have an example, but I´m particularly interesting in knowing how the android users would except that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## From the interaction point of view

People will be touching the UI a lot: long press, swipe, drag, double touch, etc.  It can be frustrating to users if the renaming feature is constantly initiated because the user accidentally touched the screen.

Comment: Thanks! I didn´t think that, I that´s right! It would be so frustrating...thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would make an edit icon appear when pressing and holding a list item for a while - this is always the first thing I try when it comes to edit stuff. By using an edit icon (or menu) appear - the user won't be transferred into a new location which can be confusing.

The Facebook app is using a swipe from right to left to make the Edit menu appear. It took me a long time before I found that one out - not sure why they went that road.

As a backup - I would put edit menu list item under the menu that opens when pressing the Android device's menu button. That's where I (and probably a lot of other users) secondly checks for functions.